# Getting a gunicorn and Python bad interpreter error in docker container [multi-stage]

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to develop a multi-stage Dockerfile for my Flask application. I use Ubuntu as my base image to build the modules and then use a smaller python image in the release image.

However, when I try to launch my Flask server, I get the following error

`/var/endpoint/run.sh: /opt/venv/bin/gunicorn: /opt/venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

The current method I am using is to first install all the required packages into a virtual environment and then copy the virtual environment from the base image to the release image. That does not seem to work.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as builder

WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-venv cmake build-essential pkg-config libgoogle-perftools-dev git python3.7 python3-pip python3.7-dev python3-setuptools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Setup the virtualenv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip==19.0 && python -m pip install sentencepiece==0.1.82 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt



FROM python:3.7-slim as app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apache2

COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv

WORKDIR /var/endpoint

COPY app.py /var/endpoint/

USER user

COPY scripts/* /var/endpoint/scripts/
COPY run.sh /var/endpoint/

RUN chmod +x /var/endpoint/run.sh

# Copy over the apache conf file and perform the required config
ADD model.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN a2ensite model
RUN echo "Listen 5000" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Run the script to start apache and gunicorn
CMD /var/endpoint/run.sh
```

My **run.sh** file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

service apache2 start
gunicorn --workers 1 --threads 4 app:app --timeout 900
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker Also, you should move Apache httpd to its own container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python virtual environments are very specific to the single Python they were created on.  If there are different installation paths or Python build options, the virtual environment will fail on a different Python.  In a Docker setup, you could copy a virtual environment from one build stage to another if they had the same base image, but in your case you're creating the virtual environment based on whatever Ubuntu 18.04 has, and then running it on a different Python build from the `python` image.

The flip side of this is that (as your second stage already shows) the `python:...-slim` images are based on Debian, and almost all of the installation mechanics and package names are the same between Debian and Ubuntu.

So, in your first build stage:

- Start `FROM python:3.7-slim`, the same as the runtime stage.  (Consider [making the exact version a build ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) so you don't need to type it twice.)
- Don't `apt-get install python3.7` or related packages, they will already be in the base image.

In the final image you're trying to run two programs, an Apache reverse proxy and your application.  I'd recommend running these as two separate containers (you can use a tool like Docker Compose to orchestrate this).  That simplifies the second build stage setup; you could make the final line be `CMD gunicorn ...` without an intermediate script.  (You may need to explicitly specify `gunicorn --host 0.0.0.0`  for it to be reachable from the Apache container.)

Comment: I'd also point out that using Docker negates the need for a virtualenv

Comment: The question has the one useful exception to that: the first stage installs a bunch of build tools (`apt-get install build-essential` brings along a _lot_ of stuff), and then the second stage copies out the virtual environment but not the build tools.  You can also compile dependencies to wheels in the first stage and then install those in the second stage, but you do wind up with an extra copy of the `*.whl` files.